# sum of $\sum _1^\infty \frac{1}{n^{n^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

what the exact value of this series:
$$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{n^n}} \approx 1.0625$$

it is clearly converges, my approach was to turn $n^{n^n}$ to infinity series with:

$$ x^{x^x} = e^{e^{x\log x} log x}$$

seems to me a very long way if it works, there is a better approach?

Comment: The better approach is to sum the thing up literally, just the way it is. First 4 terms will already give you **thousands** of correct decimal digits, for Christ's sake!

Comment: And if you want the closed-form expression, well, why would it have one? The simpler sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^n}$ does not. Well, it kinda does (that thing with $\int\limits_0^1{dx\over x^x}$), but it's basically useless; who needs an answer which is more complicated than the question?

Comment: you can solve that series numerically, and many others, but it is interesting to find analytical expression to that series, or an integral form, I think that it is possible to find an integral form for that but I'm not sure.

Comment: I doubt that. But I'm not sure either. Well, chances are someone more knowledgeable might come this way and help us out.